# New Sitefinity site won't start after installing Nuget packages

Tags: sitefinity

I'm attempting to install Sitefinity CMS using these instructions
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/install-sitefinity

After the nugget packages install successfully, I am unable to run the site.

I am forwarded to the URL http://localhost:55390/Sitefinity/Licensing?ReturnUrl=%2 where an error occurs.

It looks as though it's looking for a license file, but this should not be necessary until the next step.

Here is the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
> assemblyInfo Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
> execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
> code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: assemblyInfo
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
> assemblyInfo]
> Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ControlUtilities.GetTextResource(String
> fileName, Type assemblyInfo) +371
> Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ControlUtilities.GetTemplate(String
> virtualPath, String resourceFileName, Type assemblyInfo, String
> templateDeclaration, Boolean addChildrenAsDirectDescendants) +1072
> Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ControlUtilities.GetControlTemplate(TemplateInfo
> info) +629
> Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ControlUtilities.GetTemplate(TemplateInfo
> info) +13
> Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.RouteHandlerBase.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext
> requestContext) +91
> System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase
> context) +174
> System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) +82
> System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +201    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +73
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.8.4330.0

Comment: If you have a valid license file drop it into /App_Data/Sitefinity and it might just bypass it.

Comment: That helped. Once I put the license file in the folder I started getting a different error. So I copied the dlls from the other project as well.